# calling private function from public function in jquery plugin pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm new at this, so bear with me,

I have the following type of plugin pattern

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
  'use strict';
        defaults = {..}
    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin ( element, options ) {
        this.init();
    }
    Plugin.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            ....
        },
        privateFunc: function ( options) {
          //do private stuff
        }
    };

    $.fn.plugin = function (method, options ) {
        if (method === undefined){
          method = 'null';
        }
        switch(method){
          case 'null':
            return this.each(function() {
                if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_custom" ) ) {
                    $.data( this, "plugin_custom", new Plugin( this, options ) );
                }
            });
          case 'publicFunc':
           // do stuff with options and then call privateFunc with some data
           break;
      }
    };
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

I want to call `privateFunc` from `publicFunc` but I am unsure on how to access it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Plugin.prototype.privateFunc` isn't actually private at all; being part of the prototype implies public visibility; that means you can access it like so:

```
var plugin = $.data( this, "plugin_custom");
plugin.privateFunc();
```

Comment: so both prototype and $.fn. functions are public?

Comment: @NickGinanto The plugin instance could theoretically be accessed via `$.data()` on an element and then the prototype could be accessed in that manner ... not sure whether that's a real issue, though.

Comment: @NickGinanto Do let me know if there's anything unclear about my answer.